# Trying to get property of non-object Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

anyone can give me solution for this problem on codeigniter 3

Layout

[image: Layout]

View

[image: Controller]

Model

```
function detailpPost($slug)
{
    $this->db->where('url_post',$slug);
    return $this->db->get('posting', array('url_post' => $slug ))->row();

}
```

Mymodel

```
 public function getCategoryPost(){
    $query="SELECT * FROM kategori";
    $q=$this->db->query($query);
    $data=array();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ( $q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[$row['id_kategori']] = $row['nama_kategori'];
        }
        return $data;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please at least put forth the effort to copy & paste the actual code and the text of the error messages.  Posting links to images/screenshots is very lazy and it impedes this site's search indexing.

Comment: You need to make sure that the row id_kategory from kategori table returns same type as the row id_kategorypost from the posting table or programatically convert them in PHP to same type before trying to use the $kategori associative array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line 19 with below code

```
$nama_kategori = $kategori[$row['id_kategoripost']];
```